# tweepy on Macbook PyCharm -- "async" invalid syntax

Tags: python, pycharm, tweepy

I'm fairly new to coding, so I'm not quite sure what to do. I'm using a MacBook and downloaded PyCharm for my coding class, and so far, I've been able to figure most things out, but I'm stuck on this one.

I'm trying to get the tweepy Stream Listener to return the tweets for a certain hashtag, and this code worked without issue on the Windows computers on campus.
The code I'm running looks like this:

```
import tweepy
#override tweepy.StreamListener to add logic to on_status
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            # returning False in on_data disconnects the stream
            return False
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth, listener=myStreamListener)

myStream.filter(track=['#fakenews'])
```

On my computer, it returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/USERNAME/PycharmProjects/Homework/Twitter.py", line 7, in import tweepy
File "/Users/USERNAME/PycharmProjects/Homework/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/init.py", line 17, in <module>
    from tweepy.streaming import Stream, StreamListener
File "/Users/USERNAME/PycharmProjects/Homework/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 358
def _start(self, async):
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The last two "files" in the error are the code from the tweepy module, not any code I've written or searched through, and the error comes from one of those backend files.

I've tried changing the interpreter for my project in PyCharm, but I'm not sure what else to try. My professor looked at it and didn't want to get into the backend code (and honestly, I don't either, since I don't really know what I'm doing), so I'm stuck as to what the real issue is.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`async` is a keyword in Python 3.7 and while it's used as a parameter name in `tweepy` internals you can't use this library with Python 3.7.

From `tweepy` docs:

> Python 2.6 and 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5 & 3.6 are supported.

Comment: My project is configured to use 3.6, and that's what I'm getting the error on. I also tried 3.5 and 2.7, to no avail. 2.7 did have issues installing the tweepy package.

Comment: @erooskie It clearly states python3.7 in the error message. Could you please check if you have a correct interpreter selected in the corresponding Run Configuration?

Comment: Which interpreter/Python version do you want me to try? I've tried 3.7, 3.6, 3.5, and 2.7. I get the same error message with each one.

Comment: I made Tweepy 3.6 compatible with python 3.7 by finding the 11 occurrences of 'async' in "tweepy/streaming.py" and replaced them with a new variable name (tr_async). Now it runs fine. The issue was caused by 'async' becoming a new keyword in python 3.7.